# Is there a way through I can pass user defined value to Limit clause in neo4j

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j

I am currently developing an application using neo4j, nodejs and expressjs. I have a query: `.run('Match(n:person ) WHERE n.name =  $nameParam OR n.city =  $nameParam OR n.school =  $nameParam Return(n) Limit 10',{nameParam:searchedvalue})` which fetch 10 records. so is there any way through which i can make this dynamic so that user can enter the value of the number of records that he/she wants to view. Can we pass the limit value as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the value of `LIMIT` can be a parameter just like the others you have.

```
.run('Match(n:person ) WHERE n.name =  $nameParam OR n.city =  $nameParam OR n.school =  $nameParam Return(n) Limit $limitParam',{nameParam:searchedvalue,limitParam:limitvalue})
```

Here are the docs for valid parameters in Neo4j

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters